# Doctrine batch processing query while iterate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

In symfony4 i'm using the iteration solution as explained in [doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing)

The problem is that i need to perform a query inside the foreach cicle and if i do, the iteration ends.

```php
    //...
    $repo = this->_em->getRepository('App\Entity\EmailAddressStatus');
    // Gets 15k results
    $q = $this->_em->createQuery('select u from App\Entity\User u');
    $iterableResult = $q->iterate();

    foreach ($iterableResult as $row) {

        $emails = $row[0]->getEmails();
        foreach($emails as $email){
            // If i do this the iteration ends after first result
            $check = $repo->isEmailBlackListed($email);
            // Do something with $check and $email...
        }
        // detach from Doctrine, so that it can be Garbage-Collected immediately
        $this->_em->detach($row[0]);
    }
```

Comment: What's happening when you run `isEmailBlackListed` query? Do an exception is thrown? It can't stop the `foreach` like that ^^'

Comment: No errors, simply if i perform any other kind of query, the EntityManager considers ended the Users result set. Just like the resource that keeps in memory the resultset is erased by the "isEmailBlackListed" query (or, as i said, any other query)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to select the users with JOIN to EmailAddressStatus so that you get only valid users like this:

```
$this->_em->createQuery('select u From App\Entity\User u JOIN App\Entity\EmailAddressStatus s WITH s.email = u.email AND s.status <> ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, 'not-allowed-status');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've made a mistake writing the sample code, `User.email` is an array so i can't use it for join. I'm editing the original code.

Comment: then you should collect the users to detach in first foreach and then detach them in a second foreach.